# Логика работы заказа и корзины django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Вопрос чисто логики работы (без кода). Например у нас есть корзина привязанная к пользователю

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    """ Корзина """
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Покупатель')
    products = models.ManyToManyField('CartProduct', blank=True, related_name='related_cart')
    final_price = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Общая цена')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Корзина'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Корзины'

class CartProduct(models.Model):
    """ Объект корзины """
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Покупатель')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, blank=True)
    final_price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Общая цена', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.final_price = self.quantity * self.product.price
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Объект: {} (для корзины)".format(self.product.title)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Объект корзины'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Объекты корзины'
class Order(models.Model):
    """ Заказ """
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Покупатель')
    products = models.ManyToManyField('OrderItem', blank=True, related_name='related_order')
    billid = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    comment = models.TextField(default='BagleyEcommerce')
    final_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Заказ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы'


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    """ Предмет заказа """
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Покупатель')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, blank=True)
    final_price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Общая цена', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.final_price = self.quantity * self.product.price
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Объект: {} (заказ)".format(self.product.title)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Объект заказа'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Объекты заказа'
```

Вопрос: можно ли привязать order сразу к корзине?
Или человек нажал кнопку оплатить (создался order привязанный к корзине) после человек добавил к корзине еще товара и оплатил. После покупки ему выдадут товар который в корзине (был до оплаты или после?) Или тогда нужно дублировать заказ в order как у меня?

Если не понятно пишите в комментарии, постараюсь ответить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я тоже когда то писал интернет-магазин книг, но так и не дописал его.
Сделал только возможность покупки товара не зарегистрированным пользователем.
вот мой репозиторий, может поможет чем  https://github.com/ZheniaGreenTea/online-store
там корзина описана не как модель, а вынесена в отдельный файл services.py

Даже помню, что пришлось учить основы джава скрипта, чтобы добавление и удаление
товара происходило красиво без перезагрузки страницы.

Вот этот классный вопрос ты задал "После покупки ему выдадут товар который
в корзине (был до оплаты или после?)". Это наталквает к тому, что должна  быть
продумана система оплаты: онлайн картой, доставка почтой, курьером, самовывоз.
И раз так в ордере должен быть также статусы заказа: оплачен, ожидает оплаты, не оплачен,
доставленю.

По поводу "Или тогда нужно дублировать заказ в order как у меня?". Вообще идея тоже здравая.
Мой преподаватель настаивал, чтобы сделать копию ордера, потому что когда то ему привезли не тот товар который он
заказывал. Изменили описание товара на сайте и ему пришлось вытаскивать старую страничку из кеша,
чтобы доказать, что описание товара на сайте было изменен уже после покупки.